# Can I specify the aws s3 index document from a subfolder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a aws s3 bucket named localtobucket. Now I want to host a static website. For this I need to specify a index document `index.html` and a error document `error.html` file. When the `index.html` and `error.html` is in the root directory of the s3 bucket i.e:

```
localtobucket/index.html
localtobucket/error.html
```

it works fine for this configuration.

But what if my `index.html` and `error.html` is inside a subfolder called `project` and not in the root directory, i.e:

```
localtobucket/project/index.html
localtobucket/project/error.html
```

How can I specify these to index document and error document?

Comment: Have you tried `project/index.html` and  `project/error.html`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work.

Comment: It should work. When people access `project/`, it should return `project/index.html`. If that is not true for you, please edit the question to show FULL details of how you have configured and tested this, so that we can try to reproduce your situation.